# Greatest of three columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to compare multiple columns and come with the maximum value among different columns

For three columns I came up with the below query which works fine

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN col1 >= col2
              AND col1 >= col3 THEN col1
         WHEN col2 >= col1
              AND col2 >= col3 THEN col2
         WHEN col3 >= col1
              AND col3 >= col2 THEN col3
         ELSE col1
       END AS Max_number 
    FROM   (VALUES (1,2,3),
                   (1,2,3),
                   (1,2,3)) tc (col1, col2, col3)
```

But things are getting complicated when I want to compare more than 3 columns. Is there any simpler way to do this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this [`Table Value Constructor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) trick

```
SELECT (SELECT Max(col)
        FROM   (VALUES (col1),
                       (col2),
                       (col3)) tc(col)) AS Max_number
FROM   (VALUES (1,2,3),
               (1,2,3),
               (1,2,3)) tc (col1, col2, col3)
```

Additionally it handles `NULL` values as well

Answer (score 2):

As a note, the logic using `case` is not as hard as it seems:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN col1 >= col2 AND col1 >= col3 THEN col1
             WHEN col2 >= col3 THEN col2
             ELSE col3 
        END) AS Max_number 
FROM (VALUES (1,2,3),
              (1,2,3),
              (1,2,3)
     ) tc (col1, col2, col3) ;
```

That is, you just need to compare the values in the order they are returned.  Once a value is not the maximum, it doesn't need to be part of the comparison.  So, for four values:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN col0 >= col1 AND col0 >= col2 AND col0 >= col3 THEN col0
             WHEN col1 >= col2 AND col1 >= col3 THEN col1
             WHEN col2 >= col3 THEN col2
             ELSE col3 
        END) AS Max_number
```

I prefer the method suggested by VR46, but want to point out that the `CASE` is not quite as bad as it seems.